# When to use synchronous or asynchronous connection?

Tags: boost, asynchronous, connection

I would like to know what is the best choice for a connection client-server.

I have to say I'm working with boost, and I'm not in trouble with **how** to to that, but **when**, for send, receive and connect. Could someone help-me please?

Comment: The question seems to be too vague.